# using `memmove` to remove the first character of a std::string

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors

I want to remove  the first character of a string using `memmove`

Example, a `std::string` might contain:

`./Folder/File.txt`

I want to remove the `.`

I am doing:

```
if (newStr[0] == '.')
{
    memmove(newStr, newStr+1, strlen(newStr));
}
```

and getting an error: `error: no match for 'operator+' in 'newStr + 1'`

What mistake am I making?

UPDATE: oh, I think I should be using `char*` this wont work on a `std::string`

Comment: What is a String? In C++ string is usually taken to mean std::string

Comment: `newStr.erase(0, 1);` presumably. Google would have found that, stop guessing and use the documentation.

Comment: `memmove` works on consecutive bytes, and a `std::string` is *not* a sequence of consecutive bytes.

Comment: cplusplus.org is your friend: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string

Comment: @john - what did you search? `Replace first character C++ string` didn't return that in the first 3 pages I looked at, neither did `remove first character C++ string`

Comment: @Jason I searched for `c++ string`. The top hit was http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch standard rerquires `std::string` to be consecutive.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Isn't that a recent (C++11) development?  Even so, `memmove` is _not_ the right function to use.

Comment: I don't think that `std::string` is required to be consecutive in memory (otherwise the string could not vary), and, when observing assembler (or Gimple/SSA/phiopt) generated by `g++-4.7` on GNU Linux, it is not. The `std::string` is a more complex structure.

Comment: @Basile - g++ 4.7 just isn't fully C++11 compatible yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears like your newStr is a std::string, in this case you should use newStr.erase(0,1);

See [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) for more information about erase

`memmove` is only valid if you are dealing with a buffer directly (char* or char[]). If your type is std::string, use the function that's meant for it (erase) and don't try `memmove` on the c_str.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely do not use memmove for this.  You're assuming you know the storage structure of std::string, and you're assuming the implementation isn't sharing storage among multiple std::string objects, etc.  Those assumptions will cause you pain and sorrow (and faults).